# jquery difer issues with add new post in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

There is an issue with jquery.js defer parsing. The issue is, Add New Post in WordPress shows white, nothing on screen. Rest of the things are working fine.

here is the code

```
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
return "$url' defer ";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

```
function defer_parsing_of_js($url)
{
//Specify which files to EXCLUDE from defer method. Always add jquery.js
    $files = array('jquery.js');
//let's not break back-end
    if (!is_admin()) {
        if (false === strpos($url, '.js')) {
            return $url;
        }

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if (strpos($url, $file)) {
                return $url;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
    return "$url' async='async";

}
add_filter('clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1);
```

Comment: That's, working fine with desktop, but conflicting with amp.